# Using a potentiometer to adjust a capacitor voltage

Tags: voltage, batteries, capacitor, potentiometer, comparator

Update:

The purpose of the circuit is to cause a capacitor's voltage to be set to the voltage on the wiper of a potentiometer that is connected from battery to ground.
I.e. when the potentiometer is turned, the voltage on the potentiometer wiper increases or decreases. If the capacitor's voltage is less than the potentiometer's output voltage, the output of the comparator should be high and will power the base of a transistor that will allow the capacitor to keep charging.

---

[image: I assume the schematic might look something like:]How can I compare the voltages of a battery and a charged capacitor as a circuit?

The purpose of the circuit is that there is a potentiometer connected to the battery, when the potentiometer is turned, the voltage of the battery's input increases or decreases, if the capacitor's voltage is less than the battery + potentiometer's voltage (voltage divider), the output of the comparator should be high and will power the base of a transistor that will allow the capacitor to keep charging.

Comment: I'd like to see that you got some sort of idea 'put on paper' and uploaded here, "will this circuit do what I intend it to do?", to show that you done an effort yourself.

Comment: I really don't understand how your potentiometer and your battery relate. Can you please make a schematic that includes these two things, and clearly mark the point in that schematic with the voltage that you want to compare to the capacitor voltage?

Comment: (OP has now added a schematic of their own attempt, so the question has been reopened.)

Comment: I have uploaded after long thinking what I assume the schematic might look like

Comment: Does that say Vcc is 1 V? That's much too low for any op amp or comparator I'm aware of, especially if you want it to accept up to 9 V input.

Comment: The vcc for the lm399N I believe can take that low

Comment: @MiNiMe I have drawn what I feel might be the schematic of the circuit

Comment: @Marcus Müller I have drawn what I feel might be the schematic of the circuit

Comment: that schematic is not sensible, sadly: You feed in +9V at the inverting input of the opamp, but it has only a 1 V supply voltage, if I decipher that picture correctly. Your PNP transistor has no DC path from collector to emitter, and has no observable effect on anything?

Comment: Also, you have *not* marked the point with the voltage you want to compare to a capacitor voltage!

Comment: @Marcus Müller pls all I need now are the corrections , what do you think should be changed, how should I change it and why should I.....?

Comment: @MbadughaChimuanya no, there's no way to correct what you've drawn; it just doesn't even begin to make sense. Sorry. We can't guess what you want to achieve from this.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Thanks

Comment: Voltage to be compared is the output voltage of the voltage divider (the potentiometer+ battery voltage) and the capacitor's voltage

Comment: Again, that sentence still makes no sense; the voltage over the potentiometer and the 9V do not add up, so the "+" in your sentence is plain wrong, and in your schematic, the positive side of the capacitor is always connected to 9V. So, that comparison is always the same, because "something between 9V and GND" is always smaller than "9V".

Comment: There are some problems with your circuit, as other has pointed out, but instead of bashing your circuit: what do you wanna achieve?

Comment: @MiNiMe the purpose of the circuit is that there is a potentiometer connected to the battery, when the potentiometer is turned, the voltage of the battery's input increases or decreases, if the capacitor's voltage is less than the battery + potentiometer's voltage (voltage divider), the output of the comparator should be high and will power the base of a transistor that will allow the capacitor to keep charging.

Comment: How do you get current through the transistor? A capacitor blocks DC voltage. Also the 1 V for the LM339N is not enough (read the datasheet). And again, I don't know what the purpose is, are you just making a circuit for the fun of it, or you have a function in mind?

Comment: @MiNiMe The capacitor blocks DC voltage yes that is why I said it can only allow the capacitor keep charging while the battery voltage is larger than the capacitor voltage, i.e if the capacitor reaches battery voltage it until the potentiometer is turned down thereby increasing the battery + pot voltage again allowing the capacitor to charge up to the new voltage if the capacitor has charged up to the voltage of the battery it will not do anything until battery + pot voltage divider is increased & if the capacitor has reached 9v it can't no op amp output until the capacitor is discharged again

Comment: I will add another transistor parallel to the first so if there is output from op amp i.e if the battery + potentiometer voltage is greater than capacitor voltage, I can also power something with the other transistor with base current from op amp output

Comment: Edited and then closed/reopened.

Comment: @Velvel - Many thanks for alerting me to that. I do not know how that happened! I was probably trying to delete only that line at the time and somehow it became the sole text. As I almost invariably check what I have achieved after editing - as, among other things, my typo rate is higher that I'd like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does what you appear to want.

Note that you can acieve the same result by simply connecting the capacitor to the potentiometer wiper directly - however, for many capacitor values that will take a long time for the voltage to change to the desired value when the potentiometer is adjusted.

The following circuit changes the capacitor value as rapidly as you wish it to for practical purposes. Note that while increasing the potentiometer "output" voltage will cause the capacitor voltage to increase, reducing the potentiometer output voltage will NOT reduce the capacitor voltage. This can be done with an external load.

When Vcap is < Vpot_out OA2_output is low, Q1 is on and C1 charges via R3.
R3 is used to limit charge current and may be omitted if the resultant limiting of charge rate by Q1 is acceptable (not recommended).

If V_C1 is above Vpot_output its voltage does NOT decrease using the circuit shown. An external load would allow its voltage to decrease.

As shown Vcharge, Vbattery and Vdd are all connected.
If different voltages are used for these the circuit may not function as intended. If there is a requirement for these voltages to be different the requirement should be clearly stated in adequate detail.

The chosen opamp needs to

- be able to drive its output close to Vdd.
- Have a common mode range that accepts the highest used value of Vpot_out

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feF8iw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: thank you so much for this